# well-defined and continuity of an operator $A:l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})\to l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm stuck to prove that $A:l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})\to l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z}),\; u\mapsto Au$ with $(Au)_j=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\rho_{j-k}u_k$  with $\rho\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is well-defined and continuous:

If $u\in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{Z})$, then $\|Au\|_{\infty}=\sup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|(Au)_j|=\sup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}| \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\rho_{j-k}u_k|\le \|\rho\|_{\infty} \|u\|_1$ but it couldn't be, there must be something wrong... can you help me, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Why "it couldn't be"?

Comment: why should $\|u\|_1<\infty$?

Comment: So just replace the norms: put the "1" norm on $\rho$, and the "$\infty$" norm on $u$.

Comment: is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is, for the same reason it is possible to write the inequality that you did.

Comment: okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. For any $u$ with $\|u\|_\infty\le 1$ we have $\forall j\in\mathbb{Z}$
   $$|(Au)_j|=|\sum_k\rho_{j-k}u_k|\le\sum_k|\rho_{j-k}|\underbrace{|u_k|}_{\le 1}\le\sum_k|\rho_{j-k}|=\|\rho\|_1.
   $$
   Hence, $\|A\|\le \|\rho\|_1$.
2. For a fixed $j$, i.e. $j=0$, and $u\colon u_k=\text{sign}\rho_{j-k}$ we get
   $$|(Au)_j|=|\sum_k\rho_{j-k}u_k|=\sum_k|\rho_{j-k}|=\|\rho\|_1.
   $$
   Hence, $\|A\|\ge\|\rho\|_1$.